# How to redo a try statement within a certain amount of tries

Tags: python, python-requests

Currently I have a program that has proxies and makes a request to get my ip address with that proxy and returns it back in json.

An example request back is this:

`Got Back: {'ip': '91.67.240.45', 'country': 'Germany', 'cc': 'DE'}`

I want my program to try and make a request to the url and if it does not get the request because the proxy is down I want to try again 5 times before moving onto the next ip address.

I thought this except block would work but it is not breaking out of the loop when the 5 iterations are over and I am not sure why.

My program does however work when the proxy is up for the first try as it breaks after the first attempt and then moves onto the next ip address.

Here is what I currently have:

```py
import requests
import time

proxies = [
    "95.87.220.19:15600",
    "91.67.240.45:3128",
    "85.175.216.32:53281",
    "91.236.251.131:8118",
    "91.236.251.131:8118",
    "88.99.10.249:1080",
]


def sol(ip):
    max_tries = 5
    for i in range(1, max_tries+1):
        try:
            print(f"Using Proxy: {ip}")
            r = requests.get('https://api.myip.com', proxies={"https": ip})
            print(f"Got Back: {r.json()}")
            break
        except OSError:
            time.sleep(5)
            print(f"Retrying...: {i}")
        break


for i in proxies:
    sol(i)
```

How can I make it s my loop has 5 tries before moving onto the next ip address.

Comment: an easy way to do this is have a variable that starts at 0 and add 1 to it during each iteration. Instead of using a for loop, use a while loop. while variable <= 5.

Comment: The retrying module is really nice for this kind of use-case: https://pypi.org/project/retrying/

Answer (score 1):

> My program does however work when the proxy is up for the first try as it breaks after the first attempt and then moves onto the next ip address.

It does this *unconditionally*, because you have an unconditional `break` after the `except` block. Code keeps going past a `try`/`except` when the `except` is entered, assuming it doesn't have an abnormal exit of its own (another exception, `return` etc.).

So,

> I thought this except block would work but it is not breaking out of the loop when the 5 iterations are over and I am not sure why.

It doesn't break out "after the 5 iterations are over" because it breaks out after the first iteration, whether or not that attempt was successful.

Comment: What can I do to make sure that the except will break out on the last iteration then?

Comment: It just will naturally. Why would you expect otherwise? The `except` block finishes running, then the `for` loop runs out of values from the `range`, then there is nothing left in the function. The only reason to have `break`  in the *try* block is so that it doesn't do the rest of the 5 tries when the proxy is successful.

Comment: If the question is "how do I make the loop *outside* the function stop trying proxies when the function succeeds in finding a proxy", you need to `return` something to communicate that rather than simply letting the function reach the end. For example, you could `return` the request object that you get from the `requests.get` call (i.e. `r`); and then the loop will see whether a given proxy address found the a requests object or not (falling off the end of the function and returning `None`).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can just remove `break` from the last line. If you have an unconditional `break` in a loop, it will always iterate once.

```
def sol(ip):
    max_tries = 5
    for i in range(1, max_tries+1):
        try:
            print(f"Using Proxy: {ip}")
            r = requests.get('https://api.myip.com', proxies={"https": ip})
            print(f"Got Back: {r.json()}")
            break
        except OSError:
            time.sleep(5)
            print(f"Retrying...: {i}")
        # break                      <---- Remove this line
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [retrying](https://pypi.org/project/retrying/) would look something like the following:

```
from retrying import retry
import requests

@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=5)
def bad_host():
    print('trying get from bad host')
    return requests.get('https://bad.host.asdqwerqweo79ooo/')

try:
    bad_host()
except IOError as ex:
    print(f"Couldn't connect because: {str(ex)}")
```

...which give the following output:

```
trying get from bad host
trying get from bad host
trying get from bad host
trying get from bad host
trying get from bad host
Couldn't connect to bad host because: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bad.host.asdqwerqweo79ooo', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b6bd910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

### Getting fancy

If you want to get fancy, you could also add things like exponential backoff and selectively retrying certain exceptions.

Here's an example:

```
import random
import time

def retry_ioerror(exception):
    return isinstance(exception, IOError)

@retry(
    wait_exponential_multiplier=100,
    wait_exponential_max=1000,
    retry_on_exception=retry_ioerror,
    stop_max_attempt_number=10)
def do_something():
    t = time.time()
    print(f'trying {t}')
    r = random.random()
    if r > 0.9:
        return 'yay!'
    if r > 0.8:
        raise RuntimeError('Boom!')
    else:
        raise IOError('Bang!')

try:
    result = do_something()
    print(f'Success! {result}')
except RuntimeError as ex:
    print(f"Failed: {str(ex)}")
```

Comment: would you please be so kind and post small example of this --> exponential backoff and selectively retrying certain exceptions